# Is "what would I give or not to prove myself" a right sentence?

Tags: sentence-construction

> What would I give or not to prove myself

Is this a proper sentence in English?
Does this question make any sense?
Does this sentence exist in English?

Comment: You might find [this post](http://meta.ell.stackexchange.com/questions/439/please-everyone-details-please) helpful. You'll get better answers if you can provide more details in your question.

Answer (score 1):

No. You could have "What would I give to prove myself?". The context there would be as a reinforcing reply to someone asking you precisely the same question. As in:

**Juliette:** I'm not sure I believe that you really love me. What would you give to prove yourself?

**Romeo:** What would I give? **What would I give to prove myself?** Why, I'd give everything I owned, and more!

Or you could have the negative version used in the same context:

**Romeo:** What would I give? What would I give to prove myself? Why, **what *wouldn't* I give to prove myself?**

But not, "What would I give or not give ..."